# Converting String to decimal without an array

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that converts user input to any chosen input and output. For example, the user can choose that they want to enter a hex value input and receive a binary output. My plan of attack was to take the user input as a string and then convert it to a decimal, and then from there convert that decimal value to whatever output was chosen.

So if the input is "Hello world!", my decimal value would be "72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33". But when I run my program, I only receive the value of 72. As of right now, I'm only printing it to the console to test whether or not it worked. I plan on storing it as a variable and passing it on to the desired function to convert it.

My teacher said that this could be done without an array, but I'm a bit stumped on how.

```
int main (void) {
     char inputToConvert[] = "Hello world!";
     int output = (int)*inputToConvert;
     printf("%d", output);
}
```

Comment: Your program does what you asked, it prints one number representing the first item in your character array.  If you want to print more you should consider a loop.

Comment: Right. My issue that I'm having is that I'm trying to store all of these variables into my int variable so I can pass it on to another variable. I only printed it to test whether or not it was working. Sorry, I should have clarified better.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Unless you have absurdly big `int`s on your system, you're not going to be able to stuff 12 7-bit values into a single `int`. The obvious way to avoid using an array is to process one character of input at a time with something like `getchar()`.

Comment: I think now would be a good time to go talk to one of the teacher's assistants.

Comment: I down-graded this question because it shows a lack of understanding any programming concepts. A student must learn to think, and that he or she must do all by him/herself.

Comment: String does not need to be converted because the sequence of its own small integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    //input  : hex character(0-9a-fA-F)'s string
    //output : display as bin(0,1)'s string
    char *data ="deadbeef";//input string
    while(*data){
        switch(*data++){
        case '0': fputs("0000",stdout);break;
        case '1': fputs("0001",stdout);break;
        case '2': fputs("0010",stdout);break;
        case '3': fputs("0011",stdout);break;
        case '4': fputs("0100",stdout);break;
        case '5': fputs("0101",stdout);break;
        case '6': fputs("0110",stdout);break;
        case '7': fputs("0111",stdout);break;
        case '8': fputs("1000",stdout);break;
        case '9': fputs("1001",stdout);break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A': fputs("1010",stdout);break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B': fputs("1011",stdout);break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C': fputs("1100",stdout);break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': fputs("1101",stdout);break;
        case 'e':
        case 'E': fputs("1110",stdout);break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F': fputs("1111",stdout);break;
        default:
            fputs("invalid input!\n", stderr);
        }
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to your code above I could post a solution regarding to arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGLENGTH 13

int main( void )
{
    char string[ STRINGLENGTH ] = "Hello, world";
    int valueOfString = 0;
    // STRINGLENGTH -1 won't show the '/0'' terminating string
    for( int i = 0; i < STRINGLENGTH - 1; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%c = %d\r\n", string[ i ], string[ i ] );
        valueOfString += string[ i ];
    }
    printf( "Sum of chars: %d\r\n", valueOfString );
    return( 0 );
}
```

Sure it would go without arrays but I think the effort is not worth it, when you get the same result in the end.